# Open specific pages on cards

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a grid with cards, but I'm not being able to make links to the specific pages.

If they could do it any other way, i'd be very graded.

```
    body: Container(
          child: GridView(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,mainAxisSpacing: 2,crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                childAspectRatio: 1.5),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Breakfast',textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/breakfast.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Breakfast',textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/lunch.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap each card with a `GestureDetector` and use the `onTap:` to make it push to your specific page.

```dart
GestureDetector(
              onTap: () { 
                Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourRoute());},
              child: Card(
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Breakfast',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/breakfast.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```